# WSL - Having issues when running npm install

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, unix, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run npm install on a project but I keep getting this error

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path /home/mvargas/work-repos/red-keep/node_modules/@pm2/io/node_modules/semver/bin/semver
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/home/mvargas/work-repos/red-keep/node_modules/@pm2/io/node_modules/semver/bin/semver'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mvargas/.npm/_logs/2021-04-15T01_14_50_914Z-debug.log
```

I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04lts, node version is 15.14.0 and npm version is 7.7.6

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Downgraded to node 10